# Why does this method not work?

Tags: java, audio, audio-streaming

```
public AudioInputStream append(AudioInputStream main, AudioInputStream s) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {
    AudioSystem.write(new AudioInputStream(
             new SequenceInputStream(main, s),     
             main.getFormat(), 
             main.getFrameLength() + s.getFrameLength()), AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File("/home/nikkka/Desktop/alphabet/result_for_watch.wav"));
    return AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("/home/nikkka/Desktop/alphabet/result_for_watch.wav"));
}
```

It's supposed to append audio files, but it always returns the last file, not both of them!... What's the problem? :S

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns the last file"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see this only returning the second (s) AudioInputStream is if there was a problem reading in the first one.
I would suggest breaking your method down some. Here I have expanded the method some in order to add some logging statements and make it more verbose. I did not change anything functional.

```
public AudioInputStream append(AudioInputStream main, AudioInputStream s)
            throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {

        SequenceInputStream sis = new SequenceInputStream(main, s);

        long length = main.getFrameLength() + s.getFrameLength();
        logger.debug(main.getFrameLength() + "+" + s.getFrameLength() + 
                    "=" + length);

        AudioFormat fmt = main.getFormat();

        File file = new File("c:/MyNew.wav"); //changed for testing

        AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(sis, fmt, length);
        int size = AudioSystem.write( ais, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, file);
        logger.debug("Wrote :" + size);

        return AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    }
```

Also, *ensure you are catching and logging your errors in case something is thrown*. In my test case everything worked ok. Check the log statement added which shows the size of the file before and after, also they ensure what is written is >= to that value.

Making the method more verbose will help locate the problem. With it more verbose like this will allow you to step through with a debugger easier as well. Once you find the source of the problem you can revert back to the more compact way if you wish.

Comment: what doesn't work? is there an error? Can you tell me what is shown in your output?

Comment: From my code above, I added logger statements. What do you see from that?

Comment: you should see something like: 20191+13921=34112
Wrote :136492